# How to enable frontend editing in Django CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

How exactly do I enable front end editing in Django CMS 3.5.2?

I added this to the top of my template:

{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags static %}

and I added {% placeholder "content" %} to the body.  This works in  the sense that I can use it in the structure toolbar but it doesn't show up as an editable field when I hover the mouse over it.

I don't want to use {% render_model ... %} as I'm not creating a new model.

I know how to use Django but its not helping me much here as DjangoCMS doesn't make it obvious what variables are passed into the template.

Please, How do I go about this?

Comment: Have you remembered to include `{% cms_toolbar %}` straight after the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Yes, I had done that.

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean by "it doesn't show up as an editable field"? If you've got a placeholder, from the structure view you get the '+' icon to add plugins to placeholders. You add content to it that way. If you have `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` in your settings that may restrict what plugins can be added to placeholders.